# Semantic UI dropdown change handler

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

I have the following dropdown using Semantic UI:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown select-language">
    <input name="language" type="hidden" value="fr-FR">
    <div class="text">French</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu ui transition hidden">
        <div class="item" data-value="en-US">English</div>
        <div class="item active" data-value="fr-FR">French</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the jQuery side I init it:

```
$(".select-language").dropdown()
```

How can I add the `change` handler?

The only thing related to this I found in the [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/settings)  is:

> **onChange(value, text)**
>
> Context: Dropdown
>
> Is called after a dropdown item is selected. receives the name and value of selection.

This sounds a little confusing for me. How can I use it?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BJyQ7/)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Actually, there are three ways to bind the event:

```
// globally inherited on init
$.fn.dropdown.onChange = function(){...};

// during init
$('.myDropdown').dropdown({
 onChange: function() {...}
});

// after init
$('.myDropdown').dropdown('setting', 'onChange', function(){...});
```

Comment: upvote for the change of settings after the init. Can be useful in many situations

Comment: according to the Documentation, what is `choice` in  `onChange: function (val, text, choice)` and how should one use it?

Answer (score 20):

It seems that `onChange` setting can be added when creating the dropdown:

```
$(".select-language").dropdown({
    onChange: function (val) {
        alert(val);
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BJyQ7/1/)

Comment: BTW, how can we change its  value="fr-FR" to "anything_else"?

Comment: @TheMouseMan Ask a question for that. If you link it here, I will try to give you a good answer.

Comment: [Here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715193/dropdown-semantic-ui-change-the-hidden-filed-values) Thanks.

Comment: @TheMouseMan I voted your question. I made a little research, but I didn't find anything useful yet. If I find a good answer I will post it. Maybe others will be faster than me. :-)

Comment: For me, tt is storing the value in db but it is storing with "\r\n     Value     \r\n    ". Tried trimming not liking it atm. thanks for the votes up.

Comment: @TheMouseMan Sorry for delay, but I finally found [a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23980469/1420197) for you problem. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me. I needed the value somewhere else but i managed with global variable.

Comment: Is there a possibility, to get the content value? So, when I change the language in this FIDDLE (http://jsfiddle.net/BJyQ7/1/), how can I get the selected language an not the selected data-value?

Comment: How should one, get the `select`, onChange?

Answer (score -2):

```
    jQuery('.ui.ekstensi.fluid.dropdown').dropdown('setting','onAdd',function (val,text,choice) {

    alert(choice);
    }).dropdown('setting','onRemove',function (removedValue, removedText, removedChoice) {
    //your action here
    alert(removedValue);

    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dankerizer/gqx6fo1v/)

Comment: Although the code may speak for itself providing some details would help improve the quality of your answer!