# Semantic UI Dropdown: Change the hidden field values?

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I am working with semantic-ui dropdown. I am wondering on how to change the values in hidden field based on user selection from the dropdown list ? [Related Question may be!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817669/semantic-ui-dropdown-change-handler).

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown select-language">
    <input name="language" type="hidden" value="Alpha-Male">
    <div class="text">Gender</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu ui transition hidden">
        <div class="item" data-value="Alpha-Male">Male</div>
        <div class="item active" data-value="Alpha-Female">Female</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please review my answer and give me feedback. Sorry for delay. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked out the source code of SemanticUI library and I found that the module functions are stored in `data()` using jQuery.

So, to access dropdown methods for your element you will do:

```
 $(".ui.selection").data().moduleDropdown
```

Change value is actually [`action.activate(text, value)` function](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/51bcedb7d1a3691e061e63e8e539482cea161aa4/build/packaged/javascript/semantic.js#L4876-L4884).

For example, to set `Alpha-Female` value you will do:

```
 $(".ui.selection")
   .data()
   .moduleDropdown
   .action
   .activate(undefined, "Alpha-Female")
 ;
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BJyQ7/32/)